# Merge a column of URLs with a column of values

Tags: google-sheets

I have two columns in a spreadsheet, "name" and "LinkedIn URL". I'd like to remove the "LinkedIn URL" column and just turn all the names into links to their corresponding url. Is there an easy way to do this without manually copying each link and manually applying the link to the cell?

After creating this new column I would like to remove the original two columns.

Answer (score 2):

you can hyperlink it and repaste it:

```
=INDEX(HYPERLINK(B2:B; A2:A))
```

where A are names and B are urls

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I created a new column and put the above into it. This works great! However, it then breaks when I go to remove the original column of labels. I tried repasting but it seems to copy the formula in the copy of the created column. Is there a way to copy the value without copying the formula that created it?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst try: `=INDEX({""; HYPERLINK(B2:B; A2:A)})` in row 1, and copy it from row 2

Comment: Hey, tried that just now, it results in the same problem. To be clear what I'm doing: I have the two existing columns, "name" and "url". I create a new column "linked name" and paste the formula into it. It successfully creates a column of names linked to the correct value. However, when I then go to remove the original two columns the formula breaks and gives `#REF!` errors. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst yes. formulae always work in real-time. there is no future/past state for the formula so it will always recalculate. what you should suppose to do is the following: use formula (the 2nd one suggested in comment above and use it in row 1) to create your desired result and then copy (range from row 2 downwards) and repaste (copied range into new column or into same column where formula sits - in this case, you will get #REF! error in row 1 as expected) and only at this stage you can change/remove your name/url columns